# How to make a pair of two elements unique in MySql?

Tags: mysql, ddl, unique-constraint

I have the table 'Vote' in MySql, with columns 'user_Id' and 'proposal_Id' and I want to make the combination between these two as an unique record in Vote table.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a unique constraint on a combination of columns:

```sql
ALTER TABLE vote
ADD CONSTRAINT uc_vote UNIQUE (user_id, proposal_id);
```